# S3 grant object access to users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Disclaimer: I'm new to AWS.

I have a use case where I need to grant read permissions to an object in an S3 bucket to a list of users. All objects are in the same bucket. I'm using Cognito for user authentication.

I've tried using ACL through Java SDK but had no luck. Also, I don't think IAM is usable here as the users are clients, i.e. they don't have an AWS account.

Any suggestion or correction is welcomed!

Comment: How do your clients authenticate? Have you written a Cognito-based app that they log into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to grant access to an object in Amazon S3:

- **Object Access Control List (ACL):** Not applicable for your use-case because different users will need access to different objects
- **Bucket Policy:** Can grant public access to the whole bucket or a path within the bucket. Again, not applicable because it makes objects public rather than granting access to specific users.
- **IAM Policy:** Permissions can be added to IAM Users and IAM Groups, granting them access to a bucket, path or object. However, your users are from Cognito, not IAM.
- **Pre-signed URLs:** These grant time-limited access to an object. These are ideal for your situation!

The pre-signed URL works like this:

- Users **login** to your application
- Users **request access** to a private object, or your application wishes to put a link to a private object on a web page (eg in an `<img src=.../>` tag).
- Your application **verifies** that they are permitted to access the object (using whatever business logic you write), then **generates a pre-signed URL**, specifying a **duration** that the URL will be valid
- Users can use this pre-signed URL to access the object **within the specified timeframe**

The pre-signed URL can be created in a few lines of code. It can be generated within the app, without requiring a call to AWS.

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: ACL can be done using email or canonical id but my users have none of them. Writing the mentioned business logic is something I'd like to avoid, ideally it'd all be handled with Cognito and S3.

Comment: If all users receive the same access, then Cognito can do that. Once authenticated, users are assigned a Role, and that Role can grant them access to the desired bucket/path. It's not a good way to manage individual files or to provide different access to each user, but it would be fine if a large number of users are meant to receive the same access.

Comment: The concrete use case is a chat application, i.e. supporting chat groups. So users should have access only to objects in that chat group (images). User pool groups have a limit of I think 25 groups per user so that's not an option.

Comment: In that case, your application would need to determine access permissions on an individual basis and generate pre-signed URLs for users who are permitted to access the restricted content. Cognito will help identify the user, but your application would be responsible for the fine-grained permissions.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for discussion and the idea of using pre-signed URLs! I'm gonna accept your answer, even if it wasn't what I wanted it is correct and it is what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set up a backend app that would expose a REST API to your clients.
This app can live on an instance or it could be serverless.
The BE app will contain the logic for the user rights on S3.
The S3 buckets will be private, and only the BE will have access on them.

How to setup a REST API on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (python flask)

https://camillovisini.com/barebone-flask-rest-api-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

How to setup a REST API (serverless)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html